# How to detect when user uses browser scrollbars to navigate on a long HTML page?

Tags: jquery, browser, scrollbar, jquery-events

How to detect when user uses browser scrollbars to navigate on a long HTML page? I would like to attach a function to the corresponding event with JQuery (if possible).

**P.S.:** I am not referring to JQuery's UI-slider.

Comment: What are browser slides?

Comment: OK cool.  What are slidebars?

Comment: Do you mean scrollbars?  As in when the user scrolls down your page?

Comment: Not my day lol, yes scroll bars...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking for when the user scrolls the page, you should use the jQuery `scroll` event:

http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

It helps to find these things if you use the proper terminology :-)

Answer (score 0):

`document.scrollHeight` returns the max height of scroller, and by setting value of `document.scrollTo` can move scroller.